# How to programatically transfer money from a bank account via SEPA

Tags: api, payment, bank

I am looking to transfer money via SEPA from one bank account to another - from an application.

The app needs to transfer funds in the name of the person whose bank account the funds are being transferred from - i.e. some third party gateway won't do.

1. Is there an industry standard/available API for doing this (I couldn't find one off Google)?
2. If not 1., are there specific bank accounts that allow API control?

Note: I read this SO article [How can I electronically transfer money to another account using Bank Transfer (BACS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2456408/how-can-i-electronically-transfer-money-to-another-account-using-bank-transfer) and my requirements are the same - i.e. registering a payee manually beforehand is acceptable.

Comment: Did you find an answer to this question. We are looking for the same thing.

Comment: No, I don't believe I did.

Comment: Have you looked at ISO 20022? https://tools20022.com

Answer (score 0):

Apparently Achta provides an API that connects to SEPA. See https://www.achta.com/Home/AchtaAPI